# Can I safely rely on using 'python2 <script name>' on all distro of Linux?

Tags: linux, python

I'm updating this BASH installer script that may get run on many different Linux distributions, there's a python 2 script that needs to get run. From the versions I've tested I'm able to use `python2 <script name>` but I was wondering if I can rely on that being available always.

Comment: Not every distribution has Python software packages installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally python2 would be available on all linux distros , specially where the distribution has moved on to using python3,a better option would be check with something like **type python  and then python -v on the output from type** , and if turns out to be py3 ask the user to enter the location for py2